# Sequence and convergence of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence. Assume that both $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ converge to the same $L$. Prove carefully that $(a_n)$ also converges to $L$

I was thinking that $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ are both subsequences of $(a_n)$, one for even numbers and the other for odd numbers. But I don't know how to put it together.

Comment: In fact if you divide $n$ by $4$ for example this is also true for the remains of the euclidean algorithm of division. Here are the $0,1,2,3$ and thus you have to show it for the subsequences $a_{4n},a_{4n+1},a_{4n+2},a_{4n+3}$

Comment: $a_{2n}->L$<=> for every $ε>0$ there is a $k\in \Bbb N :|a_{2n}-L|<ε$ for every $2n\geq k$. Same for $a_{2n+1}$ we have a $m$ : $|a_{2n+1}-L|<ε$ for every $2n+1\geq m$. Take $b=max(k,m)$ then for $n\geq b$ you have what you desire

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $L$. There are $m,n\in \Bbb N$ such that $a_{2k}\in U$ and $a_{2l+1}\in U$ for all $k>m, l>n.$ Can you now find an index $p$ in function of $m$ and $n$ such that $a_q\in U$ for all $q>p$ ?

Comment: Basically you are saying to find an index in which they both are contained. I mean $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$

Comment: What choice for $p$ could you make such that if $q>p$ and $q$ is odd i.e. $q=2l+1$ for some $l$, then $l>n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to get control of $|a_n -L|$ for large $n$. But, depending on if $n$ is even or odd, $|a_n - L| = |a_{2m}-L|$ or $|a_n-L| = |a_{2m+1}-L|$ for a judicious choice of $m$. So, your problem boils down to using the control you have over the even and odd sequences to gain control over the entire sequence.

Comment: $a_n = a_{2m}$ OR $a_n = a_{2m+1}$, certainly not "and". Start by: Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $m \geq N$ then $|a_{2m}-L| < \epsilon$. Take $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $m \geq M$ then $|a_{2m+1}-L| < \epsilon$. Now, use the hint to show that if $n \geq 2 \max(N,M)$ then $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: You certainly need to take into account the even and odd terms, since $a_n$ has to deal with both. Also, even though you haven't seen the max in class, it's a good tool and you will likely use it often in this sort of way when you need to gain control of one sequence using the control you have over other sequences. Of course, if you think it looks nicer, you could say: Let $K = \max(N,M)$ and for $n \geq 2K$..

Comment: And it won't matter which one we take because they are both inside $(a_n)$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary. If you want to show that $|a_n - L|< \epsilon$, you don't get to choose $\epsilon$, you need to take an arbitrary one. Since $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ both converge, you can go out far enough into the tail of each sequence so that they are closer to $L$ than the arbitrary choice of $\epsilon$ you take beforehand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11371/discussion-between-tom-and-orchid-fibio)